# In what writings did Bertrand Russell criticize the epistemology of Rene Descartes?

Tags: reference-request, descartes, bertrand-russell

Could someone please list the works?

Answer (score 2):

Russell's book "A history of Western philosophy" contains a section on Descartes.

Of course, Russell criticises certain aspects of Descartes philosophy, e.g. that Descartes' dualism creates unsolved problems. Moreover Russell considers the constructive part of Descartes' epistemology as well as his proofs for the existence of God as lacking original ideas. But Russell emphasizes the importance of the "cogito, ergo sum". The overall estimation by Russell is positive.